# "WaitCondition timed out. Received 0 conditions when expecting 1" cloudformation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

this is a cloudformation template code in json. While creating wait handle it gives me an error saying that "WaitCondition timed out. Received 0 conditions when expecting 1" What does it mean ? should i remove that part of code and run again? please help

```
{
 "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

 "Description" : "Install a single-instance WordPress deployment using an    Amazon RDS database instance for storage.,

 "Parameters" : {

   "KeyName": {
  "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances",
  "Type": "String",
  "MinLength": "1",
  "MaxLength": "255",
  "AllowedPattern" : "[\\x20-\\x7E]*",
  "ConstraintDescription" : "can contain only ASCII characters."
},

"InstanceType" : {
  "Description" : "WebServer EC2 instance type",
  "Type" : "String",
  "Default" : "m1.small",
  "AllowedValues" : [ "t1.micro","m1.small","m1.medium","m1.large","m1.xlarge","m2.xlarge","m2.2xlarge","m2.4xlarge","m3.xlarge","m3.2xlarge","c1.medium","c1.xlarge","cc1.4xlarge","cc2.8xlarge","cg1.4xlarge"],
  "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
},

"DBClass" : {
  "Default" : "db.m1.small",
  "Description" : "Database instance class",
  "Type" : "String",
  "AllowedValues" : [ "db.m1.small", "db.m1.large", "db.m1.xlarge", "db.m2.xlarge", "db.m2.2xlarge", "db.m2.4xlarge" ],
  "ConstraintDescription" : "must select a valid database instance type."
},

"DBName": {
  "Default": "wordpress",
  "Description" : "The WordPress database name",
  "Type": "String",
  "MinLength": "1",
  "MaxLength": "64",
  "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*",
  "ConstraintDescription" : "must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters."
},

"DBUser": {
  "Default": "admin",
  "NoEcho": "true",
  "Description" : "The WordPress database admin account username",
  "Type": "String",
  "MinLength": "1",
  "MaxLength": "16",
  "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*",
  "ConstraintDescription" : "must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters."
},

"DBPassword": {
  "Default": "password",
  "NoEcho": "true",
  "Description" : "The WordPress database admin account password",
  "Type": "String",
  "MinLength": "8",
  "MaxLength": "41",
  "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z0-9]*",
  "ConstraintDescription" : "must contain only alphanumeric characters."
},
"SSHLocation" : {
  "Description" : " The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
  "Type": "String",
  "MinLength": "9",
  "MaxLength": "18",
  "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
  "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
  "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
}
},

 "Mappings" : {
"AWSInstanceType2Arch" : {
  "t1.micro"    : { "Arch" : "64" },
  "m1.small"    : { "Arch" : "64" },
  "m1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "64" },
  "m1.large"    : { "Arch" : "64" },
  "m1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "64" },
  "m2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "64" },
  "m2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "64" },
  "m2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "64" },
  "m3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "64" },
  "m3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "64" },
  "c1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "64" },
  "c1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "64" },
  "cc1.4xlarge" : { "Arch" : "64HVM" },
  "cc2.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "64HVM" },
  "cg1.4xlarge" : { "Arch" : "64HVM" }
},

"AWSRegionArch2AMI" : {
  "us-east-1"      : { "32" : "ami-31814f58", "64" : "ami-1b814f72", "64HVM" : "ami-0da96764" },
  "us-west-2"      : { "32" : "ami-38fe7308", "64" : "ami-30fe7300", "64HVM" : "NOT_YET_SUPPORTED" },
  "us-west-1"      : { "32" : "ami-11d68a54", "64" : "ami-1bd68a5e", "64HVM" : "NOT_YET_SUPPORTED" },
  "eu-west-1"      : { "32" : "ami-973b06e3", "64" : "ami-953b06e1", "64HVM" : "NOT_YET_SUPPORTED" },
  "ap-southeast-1" : { "32" : "ami-b4b0cae6", "64" : "ami-beb0caec", "64HVM" : "NOT_YET_SUPPORTED" },
  "ap-southeast-2" : { "32" : "ami-b3990e89", "64" : "ami-bd990e87", "64HVM" : "NOT_YET_SUPPORTED" },
  "ap-northeast-1" : { "32" : "ami-0644f007", "64" : "ami-0a44f00b", "64HVM" : "NOT_YET_SUPPORTED" },
  "sa-east-1"      : { "32" : "ami-3e3be423", "64" : "ami-3c3be421", "64HVM" : "NOT_YET_SUPPORTED" }
}
},

"Resources" : {

"WebServer": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Metadata" : {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
      "config" : {
        "packages" : {
          "yum" : {
            "httpd"     : [],
            "php"       : [],
            "php-mysql" : []
          }
        },
        "sources" : {
          "/var/www/html" : "http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz"
        },
        "files" : {
          "/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php" : {
            "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
              "<?php\n",
              "define('DB_NAME',          '", {"Ref" : "DBName"}, "');\n",
              "define('DB_USER',          '", {"Ref" : "DBUser"}, "');\n",
              "define('DB_PASSWORD',      '", {"Ref" : "DBPassword" }, "');\n",
              "define('DB_HOST',          '", {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["DBInstance", "Endpoint.Address"]},"');\n",
              "define('DB_CHARSET',       'utf8');\n",
              "define('DB_COLLATE',       '');\n",
              "define('AUTH_KEY',         'f@A17vs{ mO0}:&I,6SB.QzV`E?!`/tN5:~GZX%=@ZA%!_T0-]9>g]4ll6~,6G|R');\n",
              "define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'gTFTI|~rYHY)|mlu:Cv7RN]GQ^3ngyUbw;L0o!12]0c-ispR<-yt3qj]xjquz^&9');\n",
              "define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'Jd:HG9M)1p5t2<v~+R-vd{p-Q*|*RB^&PUI{vIrydAEEiV!{HS{jN:nErCmLv`p}');\n",
              "define('NONCE_KEY',        '4aMj4KZV;,Gu7(B|qOCve[c5?*J5x1+x93i:Ey6hh/6jXh+V_{V4+hw!qE^d*U,-');\n",
              "define('AUTH_SALT',        '_Y_&8m)FH)Cns)8}Yb8b88KDSn:p1#p(qBa<~VW&Y1v}P.*9/8S8@P`{mkNxV lC');\n",
              "define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', '%nG3Ag41^Lew5c86,#zbN:yPFs.GA5a)z5*:Oce1>v6uF~D`,.o1pzS)F8[bM9i[');\n",
              "define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   '~K<y+Ly+_Ww1~dtq>;rSQ^+{P5/k|=!]k%RXAF-Y@XMY6GSp+wJ5{(|rCzaWjZ%/');\n",
              "define('NONCE_SALT',       ',Bs_*Y9:b/1Z:apVLHtz35uim|okkA,b|Jt[-&Nla=T{<l_#D?~6Tj-.2.]FonI~');\n",
              "define('WPLANG'            , '');\n",
              "define('WP_DEBUG'          , false);\n",
              "$table_prefix  = 'wp_';\n",
              "if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )\n",
              "    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');\n",
              "require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');\n"
            ]] },
            "mode" : "000644",
            "owner" : "root",
            "group" : "root"
          }
        },
        "services" : {
          "sysvinit" : {
            "httpd" : {
              "enabled" : "true",
              "ensureRunning" : "true"
            },
            "sendmail" : {
              "enabled" : "false",
              "ensureRunning" : "false"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "Properties": {
    "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSRegionArch2AMI", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },
                      { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref" : "InstanceType" }, "Arch" ] } ] },
    "InstanceType"   : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
    "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Ref" : "FrontendGroup"} ],
    "KeyName"        : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
    "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
      "#!/bin/bash\n",
      "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",

      "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" }, " -r WebServer ",
      "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
      "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? '", { "Ref" : "WaitHandle" }, "'\n"
    ]]}}
  }
},

"WaitHandle" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle"
},

"WaitCondition" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition",
  "DependsOn" : "WebServer",
  "Properties" : {
    "Handle" : {"Ref" : "WaitHandle"},
    "Timeout" : "600"
  }
},

"DBInstance" : {
  "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
  "Properties": {
    "DBName"            : { "Ref": "DBName" },
    "Engine"            : "MySQL",
    "MasterUsername"    : { "Ref": "DBUser" },
    "DBInstanceClass"   : { "Ref" : "DBClass" },
    "DBSecurityGroups"  : [{ "Ref": "DBSecurityGroup" }],
    "AllocatedStorage"  : "5",
    "MasterUserPassword": { "Ref": "DBPassword" }
  }
},

"DBSecurityGroup": {
  "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
  "Properties": {
    "DBSecurityGroupIngress": { "EC2SecurityGroupName": { "Ref": "FrontendGroup"} },
    "GroupDescription"      : "Frontend Access"
  }
},

"FrontendGroup" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "GroupDescription" : "Enable HTTP access via port 80",
    "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
      {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "80", "ToPort" : "80", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"},
      {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "22", "ToPort" : "22", "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "SSHLocation"}}
    ]
  }
}
 },

 "Outputs" : {
"WebsiteURL" : {
  "Value" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["http://", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "WebServer", "PublicDnsName" ]},
              "/wordpress"]] },
  "Description" : "WordPress Website"
},
"InstallURL" : {
  "Value" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["http://", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "WebServer", "PublicDnsName" ]},
              "/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php"]] },
  "Description" : "Initial installation URL for WordPress"
}
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "count" property in your WaitCondition:

```
"WaitHandle" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle"
},
"WaitCondition" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition",
  "DependsOn" : "WebServer",
  "Properties" : {
    "Handle" : {"Ref" : "WaitHandle"},
    "Timeout" : 600,
    "Count": 1
  }
}
```